# What to set in frequency when using paypal recurring gem for a plan like with forever validity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I m developing a ruby on rails application using paypal recurring gem, & i have a plan which has validity of forever, it never expires, if i want a user to subscribe for that plan which never expires & wants his billing to continue then what do i set in frequency for that in paypal ?

My Code is

```
period: :monthly, frequency: 1, start_at: Time.zone.now + 30.days
```

This is creating a monthly subscription, but for forever what to set here.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **frequency** does not say anything about **expiration** (or **cycles** or **repetitions**). And it only makes sense in combination with the **period** parameter.

With your current setup, the user will be billed every month, until the recurring contract is cancelled by either him or you.

Maybe this helps to clear up how `frequency` is used in combination with `period`:

`period: :monthly, frequency: 1` = *"every 1 month(s)"*

`period: :daily, frequency: 3` = 
*"every 3 day(s)"*

BTW: in rails you can use `30.days.from_now` as a shortcut for `Time.zone.now + 30.days`